# emacs ipython autoclear buffer after executing

Tags: python, emacs

I'm fairly new to Emacs and finally figured out how to set up python environment. I'm using elpy and iPython as python shell interpreter. My question is as follows:

After I press `C-c C-c`, the buffer on the right shows the executed result. The red box is the code being executed and the blue box is the executed result returned from python. My questions are:

1. Is there a way only showing the result?
2. And every time after the script being executed, how to set the buffer on the right only showing the current result, ie, clear previous executed results? Thanks.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way only showing the result?

*elpy* already has a custom variable for this:

```lisp
(setq elpy-shell-echo-input nil)
```

> And every time after the script being executed, how to set the buffer
>   on the right only showing the current result, ie, clear previous
>   executed results? Thanks.

*elpy* doesn't have this functionality. But you can create a wrapper function and bind it to the same keys:

```lisp
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
  (lambda (p)
    (interactive "P")
    (ignore-errors
      (with-current-buffer (process-buffer (python-shell-get-process-or-error))
        (let ((comint-buffer-maximum-size 0))
          (comint-clear-buffer))))
    (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer p)))
```

Comment: Hi, the first answer solves my question. But the second one, it says 'No inferior Python process running.‘’

Comment: Sorry, previous solution was hastily put together. It failed when the Python process did not exist. I just updated the solution.